# How do I merge a value and a range or list in python in a single line?

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, and still learning simple data handling in python.
I would like to combine 1 and range(3) to get a list `[1,0,1,2]`. What is best way to do this? 
Is there any easy way like `[1,0:3]`?

Comment: Please don't change the nature of your question and invalidate all the answers. That isn't very considerate.

Answer (score 6):

[Extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), Python3.6+

```
>>> [1, *range(3)]
[1, 0, 1, 2]
```

With numpy, there's an even more convenient/concise expression using [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.r_[1,0:3]
array([1, 0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the most concise:

```
[1] + list(range(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# The following code should introduce you to lists, variables, for loops and the 
  basic interaction amongst all of them.

# Assign variable rng the upper limit of your range.The upper limit is not considered 
  in Python ranges of any kind
# hence the number should be one more than the number you want to consider/use.
    rng = 3

# Initialize an empty list for use later.
    lst = []

# Assign variable num the value you want to add and append it to the list
    num = 1
    lst.append(num)

# Print the current list.
    print(lst)

# Use a simple for loop to iteratively add numbers in your range to the list.
    for i in range (0,rng):
        lst.append(i)

# Print the updated list.
    print(lst)


#Output : 

    [1]
    [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just count from -1 and forget all about the minueses with the absolute value

```
[abs(i) for i in range(-1,3)]
```

**output**

```
[1, 0, 1, 2]
```

*OR a genrator*

```
map(abs,range(-1,3))
```

**output**

```
<map object at 0x0000026868B46278>
```

this is the same as the first output just as a genrator

*AS A LIST*

```
list(map(abs,range(-1,3)))
```

**output**

```
[1, 0, 1, 2]
```